# The pd.Series.is_monotonic() function

Tags: python, pandas, series

In applying the is_monotonic() function I am getting an error message I can not explain. This is my code:

```
pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]).is_monotonic()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-65238a38d200> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]).is_monotonic()

TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Since I am not passing a boolean object why I am getting this error message?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: When you see "TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable," think about what that's trying to tell you.  You _call_ something with `()`.  This tells you you're calling a `bool`-type object.  The logical next step would be to see what `pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]).is_monotonic` gets you and save yourself needing to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

[`is_monotonic`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) is not method but an attribute.

Don't put the parenthesis, "()" afterwards.

```
s = pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
s.is_monotonic

True
```